# How to add content & workspace tabs in a salesforce application

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Can anybody provide me some links that could describe how can i add content and workspace(now library) tab in my existing application.

I have searched many websites but couldnt find
Any help is appreciated

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swati,

you can see how to use content and workspaces effectively [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ9DGFSo_UI). As for your question on showing it as a tab on a custom application, if you go to Setup -> Create -> Apps and edit your custom app there is a list of available tabs you can add to it including libraries and documents.

Paul

Comment: pbattisson thank u for the link but i wanna know 1 thing that if i choose Content App my newly created custom tab is visible on it along with its own tabs like (content,library,subscriptions) but when i click on my custom tab it does not redirects to my custom visualforce page instead it shows recent files content.can u tell me how to achieve it????

Comment: In that case you want to create a custom tab that goes to a custom VF page, you are not trying to utilise content as it is predesigned. Just create a custom tab with it opening a VF page as normal.